# My nested document does not show up, Mongoose, Express

Tags: express, mongoose, model, nested-documents

I created a UserSchema for a MERN stack project and  I wanted to nest documents in the created users. when I registered the user I tried to post dummy data in the nested documents just to see of they would show in MongoDB Atlas and Postman, but when i click on the arrays it shows nothing in the array even though i put information.

here is my code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ClassworkSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String,
    isDone: false
});

const OutcomesSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String, 
    isDone: false,
    isApproved: false
})

const MeetupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    location: String,
    attended: false
})
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    classwork: [ClassworkSchema],
    outcomes: [OutcomesSchema],
    meetups: [MeetupSchema],
  });


// const UserSchema = new Schema({
//     name: {type: String, required: true},
//     email: {type: String, required: true},
//     password: {type: String, required: true},
//     date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  


// })

module.exports= User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

controller

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const jwt = require ("jsonwebtoken");

const keys = require("../../config/key");


const validateRegisterInput = require("../../validation/register");
const validateLoginInput = require("../../validation/login");


const User = require("../../models/User");



router.post("/register", (req, res) => {





//FORM VALIDATION

const {errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body)


//CHECK VALIDATION

if(!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors)
}

User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then( returnedUser => {
    
    if(returnedUser) {
        return res.status(400).json({email: "Email already exists"});
    }
});


// saving user with request information to database
const newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
});

bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=>{
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        newUser.password = hash;

        newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
    });

});







router.post("/login", (req, res)=>{


const {errors, isValid} = validateLoginInput(req.body)
if(!isValid){
    return res.status(400).json(errors)
}

const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password


User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user =>{

    if(!user){
        return res.status(404).json({ emailNotFound: "Email not found"});
    }

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
        if(isMatch){


            const payload = { id: user.id, name: user.name };

            jwt.sign(payload, 
                keys.secretOrKey, 
                {expiresIn: 31556926}, 
                (err, token) => {
                    res.json({ success: true, token: "Bearer " + token });
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(400)
            .json({passwordincorrect: "password incorrect"})
        }
    })
})

});
module.exports = router;
```

server

```
const express = require("express");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const passport = require("passport");


const app = express();
const users = require("./controllers/api/users")
// const classwork = require("./controllers/api/classwork")


app.use(

    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//DATA BASE CONFIGURATION

const dbkeys = require("./config/key").mongoURI;

mongoose.connect( 
    dbkeys, 
    {useNewUrlParser: true} )

        .then(()=> console.log("database connection successful"))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

app.use(passport.initialize());
require("./config/passport")(passport);


app.use("/api/users", users);

// app.use("/api/classwork", classwork)


const port = 5000;

app.listen( port, () => console.log("server us up and running on port 5000!"))
```

[mongodb atlas, no object shows when the arrow is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDfHR.png)
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yNxx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it awaits something that is not what you pass. When so nothing will be saved to the database because it's not the right type, from the mongoose documentation it should be written like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String
  , age     : Number
  , stories : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var StorySchema = new Schema({
    _creator : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
  , title    : String
  , fans     : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```